# Update or create_by

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

What is a good way of updateing, or creating new records?

I have tried this, in Rails console is working fine, when the app runs, it doesn't.
Is there a better way of doing this?

```
landing = Landing.find_or_initialize_by(pos: k, project_id: project_id)
landing.update_attributes(pos: k, project_id: project_id)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

initialize doesn't persist to database, but create does.  Change your line of code to:

```
landing = Landing.find_or_create_by(pos: k, project_id: project_id)
```